# How do make an autocomplete for drug search?

Tags: openfda, drugs

I am making a drug search box on a webapp and was wondering if there is a way to make  an autocomplete as a user type the drug name in the searchbox?

This is the api url that  i use to search for drugs;

`https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?api_key=${drugAPI}&search=openfda.generic_name:"${Drug}"&limit=100`;

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

openFDA does not support auto complete at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this though I’m not sure what your background or current needs are so it may be best to start with something like one of these: https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/

https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/apidoc/rxterms/v3/doc.html

### http://lhncbc.github.io/autocomplete-lhc/
Let me know if you need something more specific.